# Is the total spin angular momentum $S=2$ symmetric or anti-symmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I am aware that $S=0$ is anti-symmetric, whereas $S=1$ is symmetric. But what about $S=2$ and $S=\frac{3}{2}$? Is it symmetric or anti-symmetric? Is there any general formula for identifying whether $S$ is symmetric or anti-symmetric for any given value of $S$?

Comment: what do you mean by "symmetric" and "anti-symmetric"? with respect to what transformation?

Comment: @yyy, concerning particle exchange.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your question is concerning the specific case where you look at the addition of two spin-$1/2$ particles, and then the Hilbert space of dimension four can be split into two subspaces, according to the total spin: a singlet with $S=0$ and a triplet with $S=1$. In that case, indeed the $S=0$ case is antisymmetric for exchange of the two particles, and each of the the triplet $S=1$ states is symmetric under exchange of the two particles.

This is not the general case, however. When adding, for example, two particles with $S=1$, the Hilbert space of dimension nine can be split into three sectors: a singlet $S=0$, a triplet $S=1$ and a quintet $S=2$. In this case, the $S=0$ state is given by the superposition
$$ |S=0, M=0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|m_1=1, m_2=-1\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|m_1=0, m_2=0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|m_1=-1, m_2=1\rangle $$
which is symmetric under the exchange of the two particles, instead of being antisymmetric. So your assertion that "$S=0$ is antisymmetric" pertains to a specific case.

Also note that for $S>1$, you need to add more than two spin-$1/2$ particles to get a such a total angular momentum, so a state should be anti-symmetric or symmetric under all possible permutations. The general case of combining $n$ spin-$m$ particles to get some $S \leq n/m$ multiplet of states, is quite complicated and involves [Young tableaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau).

Comment: There is *one* simple case: the maximum-possible $S$, whose representation is $\left| \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \cdots \uparrow\right>$, is always symmetric. For spin-half the symmetry alternates on your way down to $S=0$ (or $S=1/2$ if the size of your ensemble is odd). But you can’t say much more than that without getting into Young’s-tableaux territory.

Comment: @rob thank you for adding that. When you say that "For spin-half the symmetry alternates on your way down" - in general there are several different multiplets with intermediate $S$. Is that true for all of them (that is, all multiplets with the same total intermediate $S$ will have the same symmetry under exchange)? how can I see that?

Comment: counter example - looking at combination of 4 spin-$1/2$ particles: there is a single quintet, three different triplets and two different singlets. And I know that I can construct a singlet $S=1$ which is antisymmetric for exchange of particles 1 and 2 but symmetric for exchange of particles 3 and 4 - it is the direct product of $|S_{1,2}=0\rangle \otimes |S_{3,4}=1\rangle$. So there is a basis where each of the $S=1$ triplets have a definite symmetry, but they will have different symmetry: at least one will be antisymmetric and at least one symmetric

Comment: Oh, I think you’re right — I’m spoiled by systems that decompose into pairs thanks to other symmetries. So only the maximum-aligned part of my comment is actually useful; the complications begin immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the question: is there a formula? Well, there is a "procedure", and it's involved, so I will outline it here.

You start with a base space. In this case, it's the basis states of a spin 1/2 particle:

$$ |\uparrow\rangle,\ |\downarrow\rangle$$

It is 2 dimensional, so we call it a "doublet", and write it as ${\bf 2}$. The goals is to combine two of these and look for invariant subspaces, that is: permutations and/or linear combinations that form subsets that are closed under rotations.

The results is well known for spin 1/2, as they form states of total angular momentum $J$ and various $M$. Written as, $|J, M\rangle$, they are, for $J=1$:

$$|1, 1\rangle = |\uparrow\uparrow\rangle$$
$$|1, 0\rangle = \big (|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\big )/\sqrt 2 $$
$$|1, -1\rangle = |\downarrow\downarrow\rangle$$

and $J=0$:

$$|0, 0\rangle = \big (|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle-|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\big )/\sqrt 2 $$

Under rotations, the $J=1$ states mix various $M$'s to make new eigenstates still with $J=1$, but aligned with respect to a different axis. Meanwhile, the $J=0$ is invariant.

Moreover, under particle interchange, the $J=1$ ($J=0$) triplet (singlet) states are (is) (anti)symmetric.

With all that, we write:

$${\bf 2}\otimes {\bf 2}= {\bf 3_S}\oplus  {\bf 1_A}$$

which means the tensor product space of two doublets can be broken down into a tensor sum of two closed-under-rotation subspaces of dimension 3 (symmetric) and 1 (antisymmetric). (3 transforms as a vector, and 1 transforms as a scalar).

To explain how this is generalized to ${\bf N}\otimes {\bf N}\otimes \cdots$, I'll step through the procedure for two (2) doublets.

Since we have two particles (or tensor indices), we start with the number $2$. Now find all partitions of that integer:

$$ 2 = 2 $$
$$ 2 = 1 + 1 $$

Each one of these partitions can be represented by a two box Young diagram (which I can't draw in Mathjax, sorry). For each Young diagram we find all possible normal Young Tableaux (that's when you fill each box with a particle label from $1,\ldots, N$ such that all columns and rows are increasing.

The Robinson-Schendsted correspondence ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson–Schensted_correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted_correspondence)) associates each Tableaux with a representation of the symmetric group on $N$-letters ($S_N$)  that is found by computing the tableaux's "Young Symmetrizer". Schur-Weyl duality ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur–Weyl_duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality)) allows you apply those permutations to the particle labels (or tensor indices) to compute the Specht Module (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht_module). The Specht modules are the irreducible representations (irreps) appearing on the right hand side, aka ${\bf 3_S}$ and ${\bf 1_A}$.

The dimensions of the irreps can be computed with the remarkable Hook Length formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula). The result depends on the both the shape of the Young Diagram and the dimension of the fundamental representation (here, $2$).

So, to answer he question, "What are the symmetries of $S=2$", the answer is: it depends. If the basis space is a spin-1 particle (which is a 3-dimensional, vector, representation), we use the same Young diagrams outlined above and get:

$${\bf 3}\otimes {\bf 3}= {\bf 6_S}\oplus  {\bf 3_A}$$

[Side note: in terms of Cartesians tensors, this say that a rank-2 tensor $T_{ij}$ in 3 dimensions can be made into a 6-dimensional symmetric part:

$$ T^{S}_{ij}= \frac 1 2 (T_{ij}+T_{ji}) $$

and a 3-dimensional antisymmetric part:

$$ T^{A}_{ij}= \frac 1 2 (T_{ij}-T_{ji}) $$

Note that by removing the scaled trace, $\frac 1 3 T_{kk}$, the symmetric tensor can be split into a scalar and a pure 5-dimensional rank 2 tensor:

$$N_{ij} \equiv \frac 1 2 (T_{ij}+T_{ji}) -\frac 1 3 T_{kk}$$.

This is exactly the same math you get using Clebsh-Gordan coefficients to combine two spin-1 particles into a symmetric spin-2 state, and antisymmetric spin-1 state, and a spin-0 state, e.g.:

$$ |2,2\rangle = |1,1\rangle_1|1,1\rangle_2 $$

and so on with the application lowering operators. Based on the fact that it must be symmetric under interchange, we can write:

$$ |2,1\rangle = (|1,1\rangle_1|1,0\rangle_2 + |1,0\rangle_1|1,1\rangle_2)/\sqrt 2$$

as it is the only normalized symmetric combination satisfying:

$$ M = m_1 + m_2 $$

Of course, your question implies we are combining four spin 1/2 particles. So, start by partitioning $4$:

$$ 4 = 4 $$
$$ 4 = 3 + 1 $$
$$ 4 = 2 + 2 $$
$$ 4 = 2 + 1 + 1 $$
$$ 4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 $$

The first Hook length formula then tells us that the number of irreps corresponding to these partitions is 1, 3, 2, 0, 0 for spin 1/2 particles, respectively. The second Hook length formula then tells us the dimensions of the irreps:

$${\bf 2}\otimes{\bf 2}\otimes{\bf 2}\otimes{\bf 2}=
{\bf 5_S} \oplus {\bf 3_M}\oplus {\bf 3_M}\oplus {\bf  3_M}\oplus{\bf 1_M}\oplus{\bf 1_M}\oplus{\bf 0_M}\oplus{\bf 0_M}\oplus{\bf 0_M}\oplus{\bf 0_A}$$

The "M" subscript indicates mixed symmetry, that is symmetric under some interchanges, and antisymmetric under others. I included the zero-dimensional subspaces for completeness. With spin-1/2, you just can make an antisymmetric combination with 3 or more spins...which is why an atomic state only holds two electrons.

[Side note: had this been a rank-4 3D Cartesian tensor like the stiffness tensor in the generalized Hooke's law, $\sigma_{ij} = c_{ijkl}\epsilon_{kl}$, the equation would give:

$${\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 3}=
{\bf 15_S} \oplus {\bf 15_M}\oplus {\bf 15_M}\oplus {\bf  15_M}\oplus{\bf 6_M}\oplus{\bf 6_M}\oplus{\bf 3_M}\oplus{\bf 3_M}\oplus{\bf 3_M}\oplus{\bf 0_A}$$

for the invariant subspaces of $c_{ijkl}$. As an example, $\bf 15_S$ gives:

$$ c^S_{ijkl}=\frac 1{24}(c_{ijkl} +c_{ijlk} +c_{ikjl}+c_{iklj}+c_{iljk}+c_{ilkj}+c_{jikl}+c_{jilk}+c{jkil} +c_{jkli}+c_{jlik}+c_{jlki}+c_{kijl}+c_{kilj} +c_{kjil} +c_{kjli} +c_{klij}+c_{klji} +c_{lijk} +c_{likj} +c_{ljik} +c_{ljki}+c_{lkij} +c_{lkji})$$

and a $\bf 15_M$ is symmetric in the 1st three indices and antisymmetric in 1 and 4:

$$ c^{M_1}_{ijkl}=\frac 1 8(c_{ijkl} +c_{ikjl} +c_{jikl} +c_{jkil} +c_{kijl} +c_{kjil} -c_{ljki} -c_{lkji} -c_{likj} -c_{lkij} -c_{lijk} -c_{ljik})$$

...same diagram, same formula, totally different physics. It can also be applied to QCD colors, quark flavors, and so-on. That's why it's always called the *remarkable* hook length formula].

So, to answer your question: "Yes". The symmetric combinations of 4 spinors is a quintet ${\bf 5_S}$, which is spin 2. The extremal case is easy:

$$|2,2\rangle = |\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\rangle $$

Symmetry means:

$$|2,1\rangle = \frac 1 2(|\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\rangle +
|\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow\rangle +
|\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\rangle +
|\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\rangle)$$

and:

$$|2,0\rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 6}(|\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow\rangle +
|\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\rangle +
|\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\rangle +
|\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\rangle +
|\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\rangle +
|\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\rangle)$$

and so.

You can try spin 3/2 using:

$$ 3= 3$$
$$ 3 = 2+1$$
$$ 3=1+1+1$$

which gives 1, 2, and 0 subspaces, respectively, via:

$$ {\bf 2}\otimes {\bf 2}\otimes{\bf 2}= {\bf 4_S} \oplus {\bf 2_M} \oplus {\bf 2_M}  \oplus {\bf 0_A} $$

Comment: I have a question about the "mixed symmetry": can't we take the complete antisymmetric and complete symmetric components, and make at least some of them into symmetric and antisymmetric representations? I mean we have a freedom to combine states between irreps that belong to the same $S$, as this is just a change of basis. So shouldn't there be a basis transformation that will take something like ${\mathbf 3_M}\oplus {\mathbf 3_M}$ to ${\mathbf 3_S}\oplus {\mathbf 3_A}$?

Comment: @yyy I don't think so, each module is a representation of the symmetric group, which I am not an expert in. the S and A refer to all indices for tensors (or particles for spin),and there is only one S or A Young tableaux..1 row or 1 column, respectively. Check out the "Young Symmetrizer" as made from the product of the row symmetrizer and the alternating column symmetrizer...it's super non-intuitive for me, but it determines the permutations.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I will look into that